# Google maps markers: directly from database, xml or json

Tags: mysql, xml, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

What is the best way to implement google map showing markers from a database. Whether directly from the database via PHP and JavaScript, be it XML or JSON file. Which way is the fastest, safest, considering that my database currently contains more than 100 000 markers and supplementing each hour. (It is the deaily deal aggregator)

Comment: ...directly from mysql or using xml, or using json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest is json since it is smaller than xml.I'm not sure i understand "directly from mysql".
Also 100.000 records in a db is not a very big number.So don't worry too much.

Cheers

Comment: When i say directly I think to get markers from database without xml and json... just get coordinates from database with JS and put on map. I think that this way is better. Is it?

Comment: To pull data from the db you must pull them with a server side language like php and put them in a page in a certain form-xml,json- and then make the javascript request tpo get the data from that page.You can't get the data directly with javascript.